# how to save data from one dataset to another dataset and display the same value in gridview using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Actually I want to multiple search from Array , and display the both details which are in the database and  and which are not in database ,I tried this Please help me

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();

      SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
      adapter.Fill(ds);
      for (i = 0; i < MyNames.Length; i++)
       {
           for (int j = 0; j <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; j++)
           {
           if (MyNames[i].ToString() == ds.Tables[0].Rows[j][0].ToString())
               {
                   ds1.Tables[0].Rows[j][0]=ds.Tables[0].Rows[j][0];
                   ds1.Tables[0].Rows[j][1] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[j][1];
               }
               else 
               {
                   ds1.Tables[0].Rows[i][0] = MyNames[i].ToString();

                   ds1.Tables[0].Rows[i][1] = "not applicaple";
               }
           }
       }


       GridView1.DataSource =ds1;

       GridView1.DataBind();

    con1.Close();
```

Comment: What is problem. Nothing displayed? Anyway, try this: insert  `ds1.Tables[0].AcceptChanges();` before `GridView1.DataSource =ds1;`. .. And why not use `DataTable` instead `DataSet`?

Comment: btw. provide `cmd` in Your code, too.

Comment: When i am trying run this program getting error like this                                  System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Cannot find table 0.

Comment: Try to move code after 2nd `for` loop. Can You provide `cmd` too.

Comment: SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(conectionstring);
    con1.Open();
    string str = "select * from main where NUMBER in(" + Names.ToString() + ")";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con1);